# IdentityServer3 Authorize in custom MVC controller in identity server application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, identityserver3

I have an Identity Server 3 application used for SSO. In the same application in which the IdentityServer is running I have integrated Asp.Net MVC controllers for user registration and so on. However I have some methods which cannot be accessed without a specific role and I want to use the Authorize attribute in order to do the role check.

As per this GitHub thread https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1148 I have setup said controller to use the same base route as IdentityServer in order to be in the Owin pipeline.

In the thread there is an attribute snippet which in general does what I want. It authenticates the user and gets some of their claims, but the problem is that many claims are missing- the role claim, for example, which I need for the Authorize attribute to work. I spent many hours trying to see why there are missing claims and really want to avoid querying the database and adding them myself.

In my normal client applications the claims I get in the ClaimsPrincipal are (iss,aud,exp,nbf,nonce,iat,sid,sub,auth_time,idp,preferred_username,email,email_verified,role,website,amr). As you will see apart from sub and amr, the other claims are completely different from what I get in the IdentitySever application with the help of IdentityServerFullLoginAttribute (code below).

The question is is that even possible and why are just these claims retrieved(sub, name, amr, idp, auth_time, security_stamp)?

This is my IdentityServer config:

```
coreApp.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                Factory = factory,
                SigningCertificate = signingCertificate,
                SiteName = "Sitename",
                RequireSsl = true,
                LoggingOptions = new LoggingOptions
                {
                    EnableKatanaLogging = true
                },
                EventsOptions = new EventsOptions
                {
                    RaiseFailureEvents = true,
                    RaiseInformationEvents = true,
                    RaiseSuccessEvents = true,
                    RaiseErrorEvents = true
                },
                CspOptions = new CspOptions
                {
                    Enabled = true,
                    ScriptSrc = "'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'"
                }
            });
        });
```

And this is the said attribute I am using to allow the user to be authenticated

```
public abstract class OwinAuthenticationAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public string AuthenticationType { get; set; }

    protected OwinAuthenticationAttribute(string authenticationType)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authenticationType)) throw new ArgumentNullException("authenticationType");

        AuthenticationType = authenticationType;
    }

    public virtual void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        var ctx = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.GetOwinContext();
        var result = AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => ctx.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(AuthenticationType));
        if (result != null &&
            result.Identity != null &&
            result.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(result.Identity);
        }
    }

    public abstract void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext);
}

public class IdentityServerFullLoginAttribute : OwinAuthenticationAttribute
{
    public IdentityServerFullLoginAttribute()
        : base(Constants.PrimaryAuthenticationType)
    {
        this.Order = 1;
    }

    public override void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
        var statusCodeResult = filterContext.Result as HttpStatusCodeResult;
        if (statusCodeResult != null && statusCodeResult.StatusCode == 401)
        {
            var ctx = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.GetOwinContext();
            var url = ctx.Environment.CreateSignInRequest(new SignInMessage
            {
                ReturnUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
            });
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the controller action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("core/test/test")]
    [IdentityServerFullLogin]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public EmptyResult Test(string signin)
    {
        //return Redirect("~/core/" + IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.RoutePaths.Login + "?signin=" + signin);

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so after a bit of a struggle I managed to put something together that does the job.
I am retrieving the needed claims in OnAuthentication() in OwinAuthenticationAttribute  like this:

```
            var userManager = ctx.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            string sub = result.Identity.FindFirst("sub")?.Value;

            if (userManager.SupportsUserClaim)
            {
                result.Identity.AddClaims(await userManager.GetClaimsAsync(sub));
            }

            if (userManager.SupportsUserRole)
            {
                IList<string> roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(sub);

                foreach (string roleName in roles)
                {
                    result.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Role, roleName, ClaimValueTypes.String));
                }
            }
```

Comment: This does what I needed, but still I hoped there is a way to achieve it without adding the claims manually. Is this even possible in this scenario?